# Share post to LinkedIn using Custom URL and specify image

Tags: wordpress, linkedin-api, facebook-opengraph

I am able to successfully share a post to LinkedIn using their Custom URL API:

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin

I can specify title, summary etc. but not an **image**. LinkedIn automatically grabs the image via an **og:image** tag from the linked page.

og:images are normally above 200x200 pixels, but LinkedIn is cropping (not resizing) the image to about 180 x 110.

Wordpress generally uses a 512x512 site icon, which a lot of plugins now pickup and add by default as the og:image icon. (ie. JetPack)

How to get around this issue without adding a very small [non-square] og:image to my site/pages?

[image: LinkedIn Share Post function]

Answer (score 1):

To set the preview screen for LinkedIn sharing, set your `og:` tags...

- `<meta property='og:title' content='Title of the article"/>`
- `<meta property='og:image' content='//media.example.com/ 1234567.jpg"/>`
- `<meta property='og:description' content='Description that will show in the preview"/>`
- `<meta property='og:url' content='//www.example.com/URL of the article" />`

Source: [**LinkedIn Developer Docs: Making Your Website Shareable on LinkedIn**](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en.com).

Here's an example where it works for me:

[image]